# Convert IList<Interface> to List<Class>

Tags: oop, c#-4.0, interface

```
List<CurrentElectionService> result = new List<CurrentElectionService>();    
result = oElectionsManager.GetCurrentElectionsByEId(
    employeeId.StringToGuid(), planYear) as List<CurrentElectionService>;

Public class CurrentElectionService : ICurentElection
{
   // Implement Interface fields here
}
```

The method **`GetCurrentElectionsByEId`** returns me `IList<ICurentElection>` and I want to cast the interface into class **`CurrentElectionService`**, but it returns null. Please help.

Comment: If you use the 'as' keyword to convert you will get null if the result is not of that type. Please describe more in detail what GetCurrentElectionsByEId does.

Comment: Do you really need a `List`? Why don't you work with the `IList` the method provides? Which methods are you missing? Note that the `Enumerable` extension methods can give you all that `List` would provide.

Comment: I need to expose this metod for WCF service and I think we can't expose ILIST in WCF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use LINQ to perform your cast

```
List<CurrentElectionService> result = oElectionsManager.GetCurrentElectionsByEId(
    employeeId.StringToGuid(), planYear).Cast<CurrentElectionService>().ToList();
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out of which type the actual return value is. The `as` keywort always returns null if your actual object is not of the type you want to cast it to.

With the definition you gave you could also try this:

```
List<ICurentElection> result;    
result = oElectionsManager.GetCurrentElectionsByEId(
employeeId.StringToGuid(), planYear) as List<ICurentElection>;
```